# Intune IpadOS disable Safari quick notes

Tags: ipad, safari, mdm, kiosk, intune

I am facing the issue that I have a supervised iPad running the latest IOS and managed by Intune and running single app kiosk mode with Safari. The issue is: if you press the share option in Safari you can create a quick note from there. I tried to restrict com.apple.mobilenotes (did it at the same time and one by one)and also hide it but still, I can make quick notes. I wasn't able to find any other option.
Can someone please advise what would be the best solution?
Thanks,
Gabor